# How to find a position of Least Significant Bit (LSB) in an int? c++

Tags: c++, int, position, bit

I have to write a c++ function which swaps nth and least significant bit of an int. I found some examples and did this:

```
v1 = v1 ^ ((((v1&1) ^ (v1>>n)&1) << LSBpos) | (((v1&1) ^ (v1>>n)&1) << n));
cout<<v1;
```

v1 is an int.
v1&1 is the value of LSB.
LSBpos should be the position of LSB but I don't know how to get it. There are explanations of how to get the position of LSB that is set or clear, but I just need that position, whether it is set or not.

Comment: The least significant bit is bit number zero in C++. Do you mean the least set bit?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know the position of the LSB. And this is great because due to [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) it could be at multiple places!

Let us find some help: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit):

> #### Checking a bit
>
> You didn't ask for this, but I might as well add it.
> To check a bit, shift the number n to the right, then bitwise AND it:
>
> ```
> bit = (number >> n) & 1U;
> ```
>
> #### Changing the nth bit to x
>
> Setting the nth bit to either 1 or 0 can be achieved with the following on a 2's complement C++ implementation:
>
> ```
> number ^= (-x ^ number) & (1UL << n);
> ```

And go for it!

```
int swap_nth_and_lsb(int x, int n)
{
    // let to the reader: check the validity of n

    // read LSB and nth bit
    int const lsb_value = x& 1U;
    int const nth_value = (x>> n) & 1U;

    // swap
    x ^= (-lsb_value) & (1UL << n);
    x ^= /* let to the reader: set the lsb to nth_value */

    return x;
}
```

---

In the comment, OP said *"I have to write one line of code for getting result"*. Well, if the one-line condition holds, you can start from the above solution and turn it into a one-liner step by step.